# how to combine data serialize() and new formData with each other in jquery

Tags: jquery, ajax, serialization, form-data

for a form with only text fileds, i use this js:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: 'order.php',
    data: $('#order').serialize(), 
    success: function(data){
            $('.alert-success').html(data); 
    }
});
```

For another form for a file upload only, i have this js:

```
var file_name = $('.image').val();
var index_dot = file_name.lastIndexOf(".")+1;
var ext = file_name.substr(index_dot);

var formData = new FormData();          
formData.append('fileupload',$( '.image' )[0].files[0], file_name);

$.ajax({
    url: 'order.php',
    data: formData,
    processData: false,
    contentType: false,
    type: 'POST',
    success: function(data){
        $(".alert-success").show(); 
        $('.alert-success').html(data);

    }
});
```

Now i want to combine the 2 data: `data: $('#order').serialize(),` and `data: formData,` to each other so that i have only 1 ajax

How can i do that?
(i have already put the `input type="file"` into the first form)

Comment: You might look into using `serializeArray()` on the form to get a list of the key value pairs, and then looping over that in some fashion to push them all on to the formData the fileupload is put on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var file_name = $('.image').val();
var index_dot = file_name.lastIndexOf(".")+1;
var ext = file_name.substr(index_dot);

var formData = new FormData(this);          
formData.append('fileupload',$( '.image' )[0].files[0], file_name);

$.ajax({
    url: 'order.php',
    data: formData,
    ...
```

Note: `var formData = new FormData(this);` instead of `var formData = new FormData();`